# Sass no xampp nao funciona

Tags: xampp, sass

Boa tarde,
Estou tentando rodar o sass no xampp, mas ele nao esta funcionando. Alguem sabe me dizer se tem como rodar ou como fazer funcionar?

Comment: aparece algum erro?! Tem mais alguma coisa que você queira compartilhar apara te ajudar melhor?!

Comment: Não da erro nao, mas todas as alterações q eu faço nele não aparecem no html. So quando faço no style.css.

Comment: vc esta usando linha de comando para compilar ou algum programa para isso? tem o link do projeto em algum lugar, talvez eu possa ajudar.